# Error message 'Cannot be resolved or is not a field'

Tags: java, eclipse, interface

Right now I'm studying the chain of responsibility design pattern and am using [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29).

And I'm trying to compile this code, but I have the compiling error "isLast cannot be resolved or is not a field":

```
public class OverFive implements Discount {
    private Discount next; //
    public boolean isLast = false;

    public void setNext(Discount next, boolean Last) {
        this.next = next;
        this.next.isLast = Last; // Here is the error.
    }

    public double DoDiscount(Budget budget) {
        if (budget.getValue() > 500) {
            return budget.getValue() * 0.10;
        }
        if (this.next.isLast == false) {
            return next.DoDiscount(budget);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And now, here is the interface:

```
public interface Discount {

    double DoDiscount(Orcamento orcamento);
        void setNext(Discount next, boolean Last);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one recommendation: study the Sun Java coding standards and take them to heart.  You're breaking them too frequently in this small code sample.

Java is case sensitive: "discount" is not the same as "Discount"; "dodiscount" is not the same as "DoDiscount".

```
public interface Discount {

    double doDiscount(Orcamento orcamento);
    void setNext(Desconto next, boolean last);
    void setLast(boolean last);
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class OverFive implements Discount {
    private Desconto next;
    private boolean last = false;

    public void setLast(boolean last) {
        this.last = last;
    }

    public void setNext(Desconto next, boolean last) {
        this.next = next;
        this.setLast(last);
      }

    // this method is utter rubbish.  it won't compile.
    public double doDiscount(Orcamento budget){
        if (budget.getValue() > 500){
            return budget.getValue() * 0.10;
        }if (this.next.isLast == false){
            return next.discount(budget);
        }else{
            return 0;
        }   
    }
}
```

I think this code is more than a little confusing.  No wonder you're having problems.

Comment: Yes, I know. I did some modifications with replace function of Notepad++, so, is out of standard.

Comment: Not good.......I don't care much for your design at all.  I thought you were using Eclipse?

Comment: @Raphael: then please modify it again so that it is *in* standard. Especially if you're asking volunteers to try to read and understand your code. 1+

Comment: @Raphael: `isLast` is not a field of Discount but rather only of OverFive. Don't try to manipulate fields directly, but instead use public overrideable methods as duffymo demonstrates.

Comment: As duffyno demonstrates? Sorry, don't understand.

Comment: Hovercraft is giving me too much credit here.  He's (correctly) saying that Discount has no member variables; it's not possible with interfaces.  If you must manipulate such a thing, you have to add a method to the interface to do it.  Where did you get this code?  It's wrong from first to last.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the same type of issue as the above, but I had the same error. In my case , I was using an older version of Eclipse that apparently didn't like having a class with same name as the package. I fixed the issue by giving the package a different name.